# C - passing array to node of a linked list

Tags: c, arrays, list, linked-list, malloc

I have a 2D array already filled with integers, ready to be cut to rows and processed, and I need each row (1D array) to be passed to a node of a linked list. Each node looks like this:

```
struct node {
    int *val;
    struct node *next;
};
```

New nodes are added and linked this way:

```
struct node *addnode(int *val, struct node *next, int columns)
{
    struct node *tnode;
    tnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(*tnode));
    if(tnode != NULL) {
        tnode->val = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns);
        memcpy(tnode->val, val, sizeof(int) * columns);
        tnode->val = val;
        tnode->next = next;
    };
    return tnode;
}
```

The fragment of program that will fill each node looks roughly like so:

```
int table[rows][columns], i, j;
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    head = addnode(*table, head, columns);
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        scanf("%d",&table[i][j]);
        head->val[j] = table[j];
        printf("%d ",head->val[j]);
    };
    puts("\n");
};
```

I'm uncertain how to proceed in indicated places:

1. That's malloc for the whole node, but what should I do with malloc for `val`? I know the length of table that should be in each node, and it's `columns`, acquired in main function. Where should I allocate memory for it?
2. Above this line is the place I'd malloc enough (`columns`) memory for a single row of integers. Is it a good choice?
3. This, with the precedent loop should fill the current `head->val[j]` with adequate i-row of 2D array `table`, but it looks too good to be true. Can I leave it like that?

EDIT: I corrected it in some places, but then after trying to sort it, it returns rubbish. I'll just dump most of the code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    int *val;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *addnode(int *val, struct node *next, int columns);
struct node *mergesort(struct node *head, int column);
struct node *merge(struct node *head_one, struct node *head_two, int column);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct node *head;
    struct node *current;
    struct node *next;
    int symbol = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    //int columns = atoi(argv[1]); //until sorting works, I'll keep it at 0
    int rows = 0;
    head = NULL;
    int column = 0; //temporary until I find the way to send one argument during executing it under linux like so 'name_of_program columns < test.txt'
    int lastSpace = 0;

    do {
        symbol = fgetc(stdin);

        if (rows == 0 && (lastSpace == 0 && (isspace(symbol) || feof(stdin)))) {
            columns++;
            lastSpace = 1;
        } else if (!isspace(symbol)) {
            lastSpace = 0;
        }
        if (symbol == '\n' || feof(stdin)) {
            rows++;
        };      
    } while (symbol != EOF);

    if (ferror(stdin))
    {
        printf("Error on reading from file.\n");
    } else {
        printf("The file contains %d row(s) and %d column(s).\n", rows, columns);
    };

    rewind(stdin); //I have heard conflicting opinions on that, but in this case it works, and in the end it's a school project, not commercial code

    int table[rows][columns], i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        head = addnode(*table, head, columns);
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            scanf("%d",&table[i][j]);
            head->val[j] = table[i][j];
            printf("%d ",head->val[j]);
        };
        puts("\n");
    };  


    head = mergesort(head, column);

    for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next){
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            printf("%d ", current->val[j]);
        };
        puts("\n");
    };

    for(current = head; current != NULL; current = next)
      next = current->next, free(current);
    return 0;
};


struct node *addnode(int *val, struct node *next, int columns)
{
    struct node *tnode;
    tnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(*tnode));
    if(tnode != NULL) {
        tnode->val = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns);
        memcpy(tnode->val, val, sizeof(int) * columns);
        tnode->val = val;
        tnode->next = next;
    };
    return tnode;
}

struct node *mergesort(struct node *head, int column)
{
    struct node *head_one;
    struct node *head_two;
    if((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL))
        return head;
    head_one = head;
    head_two = head->next;
    while((head_two != NULL) && (head_two->next != NULL)) {
        head = head->next;
        head_two = head->next->next;
    };
    head_two = head->next;
    head->next = NULL;
    return merge(mergesort(head_one, column), mergesort(head_two, column), column);
}

struct node *merge(struct node *head_one, struct node *head_two, int column)
{
    struct node *head_combined;
    if(head_one == NULL)
        return head_two;
    if(head_two == NULL)
        return head_one;
    if(head_one->val[column] < head_two->val[column]) {
        head_combined = head_one;
        head_combined->next = merge(head_one->next, head_two, column);
    } else {
        head_combined = head_two;
        head_combined->next = merge(head_one, head_two->next, column);
    };
    return head_combined;
}
```

I run it in Unix like this:

```
name_of_program < test.txt
```

with test.txt having this structure http://pastebin.com/WL5brutf

Comment: where does `head` come from ?

Comment: @wildplasser `struct node *head;` if that's what you ask for.

Comment: In the new fragment `rows` and `columns` are undefined in main(). ALSO `int main(int column_to_sort)` is a strange way to use argc ...

Comment: It would help if you included a complete program that compiles without errors.

Comment: @wildplasser Corrected the first, as to the second - I have to run that program like so `name_of_program column_to_sort < 2D_array.txt`, and I have no idea how to do that other way.

@sigjuice It compiles, I just skipped the part with reading from stdin and putting it into 2D array of int, because it works as intended, and it's an embarrassing piece of code

Comment: int main(int column_to_sort) is completely wrong.  What do you get if you put printf("column_to_sort %d\n", column_to_sort) at the beginning of main()?  Also, omitting parts of your program makes it hard for other people to provide useful advice.

Comment: @sigjuice Pasted whole code, I think I get what you're referring to, but could you give me an example of correct usage?

Comment: @wildplasser All sources I could find about usage of command line arguments are written in a language I hardly understand (English in not my native language). Could you give me an example on how I could get an integer that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are passing `int *val` to the function, is using that itself in the node. If you want to discard `val` passed to the function and want to keep another copy of it, you need to `malloc` the memory. As you said you know how many elements are in the array, so you can allocate for that many and just copy the memory from `val` as

```
 tnode->val = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_of_elements); //replace num_of_elements with appropriate variable/constant
    memcpy(tnode->val, val, sizeof(int) * num_of_elements);
```

2) Yes, that is correct place.

3) Yes, you can assign values that way for current node pointed by `head`. You may want to move to next node after `j` for-loop ends and assign new values in its `val`.

Comment: I corrected the code, but then after sorting it I get only the array of the last element of the unsorted list.